# How to correct TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing with ReportLab

Tags: python, django, datatables, reportlab, python-unicode

Recently, I have been working `ReportLab`. At the moment, I would like to generate clickable Table Of Contents in PDF using `ReportLab`.

When I tried to see how it works, I keep getting this error: `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

When I tried to execute this code on Python 3.7.4 using `ReportLab` library:

```
class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        apply(BaseDocTemplate.__init__, (self, filename), kw)
        template = PageTemplate('normal', [Frame(2.5*cm, 2.5*cm, 15*cm, 25*cm, id='F1')])
        self.addPageTemplates(template)


    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        "Registers TOC entries."
        if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            style = flowable.style.name
            if style == 'Heading1':
                level = 0
            elif style == 'Heading2':
                level = 1
            else:
                return
            E = [level, text, self.page]
            #if we have a bookmark name append that to our notify data
            bn = getattr(flowable,'_bookmarkName',None)
            if bn is not None: E.append(bn)
            self.notify('TOCEntry', tuple(E))

centered = PS(name = 'centered',
    fontSize = 30,
    leading = 16,
    alignment = 1,
    spaceAfter = 20)

h1 = PS(
    name = 'Heading1',
    fontSize = 14,
    leading = 16)


h2 = PS(name = 'Heading2',
    fontSize = 12,
    leading = 14)


# Build story.
story = []

toc = TableOfContents()
toc.levelStyles = [
    PS(fontName='Times-Bold', fontSize=20, name='TOCHeading1', leftIndent=20, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=10, leading=16),
    PS(fontSize=18, name='TOCHeading2', leftIndent=40, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=5, leading=12),
]
story.append(toc)

def doHeading(text,sty):
    from hashlib import sha1
    #create bookmarkname
    bn=sha1(text+sty.name).hexdigest()
    #modify paragraph text to include an anchor point with name bn
    h=Paragraph(text+'<a name="%s"/>' % bn,sty)
    #store the bookmark name on the flowable so afterFlowable can see this
    h._bookmarkName=bn
    story.append(h)

story.append(Paragraph('<b>Table of contents</b>', centered))
story.append(PageBreak())
doHeading('First heading', h1)
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading', PS('body')))
doHeading('First sub heading', h2)
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading', PS('body')))
story.append(PageBreak())
doHeading('Second sub heading', h2)
story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading', PS('body')))
story.append(PageBreak())
doHeading('Last heading', h1)
story.append(Paragraph('Text in last heading', PS('body')))
doc = MyDocTemplate('mintoc.pdf')
doc.multiBuild(story)
```

I tried to fix this issue but I am not able to properly fix this. I appreciate your help on this please.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to pass bytes, not strings, so the issue is here:

```
bn=sha1(text+sty.name).hexdigest()
```

what you can do is change it like so:

```
bn=sha1((text+sty.name).encode("utf8")).hexdigest()
```

Also, you should really move your `sha1` import to the top of the file, no need to call it every time you run the function

Comment: It gives the same error 'TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
'

Comment: where does it give you this error? please add the stack trace to the question

Comment: 72 def doHeading(text,sty):
     73     #create bookmarkname
---> 74     bn=sha1(text+sty.name).encode("utf8").hexdigest()
     75     #modify paragraph text to include an anchor point with name bn
     76     h=Paragraph(text+'' % bn,sty)

TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: `bn=sha1(text+sty.name).encode("utf8").hexdigest()` is wrong! look closely at what i suggested, you got the `()` in the wrong places. it should be `bn=sha1((text+sty.name).encode("utf8")).hexdigest()`